# A Google Drive quota has been exceeded

Tags: google-drive-for-desktop

I need to store a dataset (120GB) in my drive to later train a model on it. If I upload it from my PC its taking a hell lot of time. So I thought I will directly download to Drive through Colab, I downloaded 20 GB tar file from the source using `wget` directly to Drive using the following:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import os
os.chdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/EGTEA")

!wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/udynz2u62wpdva6/video_clips.tar?dl=0
```

All is well and good till here. Now I am directly trying to untar it to same folder in the drive as follows:

```
!tar -xvf "video_clips.tar"
```

The video clips were being unzipped but after 2-3 minutes they were not being uploaded to drive anymore, while the code is running a pop up shows up:

**A Google Drive quota has been exceeded (most recently at 12:29:18 AM). [More info](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#drive-quota).**

I am able to redo the process again and again but it works initially but then this pop up shows up after 2-3 minutes. The whole data that's being unzipped wont cross 100GB.

I am using my college email id so there is TBs of drive space available and the internet connection is also good, I have tried this many times but at some point, this pops up and the data doesn't go into drive.

What is the problem? How do people work with large datasets on colab. Furthermore after I get these video clips, I have to preprocess them on colab itself and store the final preprocessed data (120GB) to the drive. Now I am not so sure its as simple as just running the code as I am stuck in the first part only, give me some ways to get around this issue.

Comment: Welcome to [su]. When choosing a tag, please consider the tag usage guidelines / excerpt. This question needs work to make it more practical and detailed about using computer software and hardware. At this time, it's asking about the policies of Cloud Computing service, more specifically about Google Drive quotas. Such a question doesn't look like a good fit for this site, as it might be a general reference question or question that should be addressed to a customer service or sales agent. Please check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: It might not mention maximum file sizes but that does not meet the don't exist.  It appears that limit is 5 TB but there is a daily upload limit that you likely exceed (based on your answer).

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about computer hardware and software as defined in [tour] and [help/on-topic]. The question concerns an error message when running Python code in Google Collaboratory, a web IDE. The OP has answered the question and mentions that despite the error, the code keeps running in the background, giving enough time for the file to be successfully uploaded. This might be on-topic in [so] because it's about using an IDE and about programming with Python.

Comment: @Wicket - This question most certainly is within scope here at Super User.

Comment: @Ramhound The OP is not using installable software and it's not running code on a desktop computer. Please explain how is this question on topic in [su].

Comment: @Wicket - They would have encountered the same issue if they had used the Google Drive for Desktop client or were scripting it.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think so, but I can't tell for sure. On the one hand, the problem was that the web application, in this case, Google Colaboratory, was returning an error message while the process was still running "in the background" On the other hand, there is no local software that could be analyzed / customized as part of a troubleshooting process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have found the solution.

Even after the code stops running, the drive files seem to be still getting added. So you can just ignore the warning that says "Quota limit has been exceeded".

You just need to wait till the activity stops. In my case, when the code finished running and when the "Quota limit has been exceeded" pop up showed up, I thought the data stops beings uploaded, but in the background it finishes adding the whole data to drive slowly given enough time, so essentially there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Wait one day. Google Drive file size limit is 5TB, so it doesn't look to be a problem solely related to the file size; trying again and again, you are just delaying when you can upload your file.

---

The link of the error message points to a Google Collaboratory page, more specifically to the following explanation:

> **Why do Drive operations sometimes fail due to quota?**
> Google Drive enforces various limits, including per-user and per-file operation count and bandwidth quotas. Exceeding these limits will trigger Input/output error as above, and show a notification in the Colab UI. A typical cause is accessing a popular shared file, or accessing too many distinct files too quickly. Workarounds include:
>
> Copy the file using drive.google.com and don't share it widely so that other users don't use up its limits.
> Avoid making many small I/O reads, instead opting to copy data from Drive to the Colab VM in an archive format (e.g. .zip or.tar.gz files) and unarchive the data locally on the VM instead of in the mounted Drive directory.
> Wait a day for quota limits to reset.

Please note that it says **Wait a day for quota limits to reset**.

From [Storage and upload limits for Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172541?hl=en)

> #### Drive upload limits
>
> Individual users can only upload 750 GB each day between My Drive and all shared drives. Users who reach the 750-GB limit or upload a file larger than 750 GB cannot upload additional files that day. Uploads that are in progress will complete. The maximum individual file size that you can upload or synchronize is 5 TB.

From [Files you can store in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en)

> ##### File sizes
>
> The following are the maximum file sizes you can store in Google Drive:

...

> All other files
>
> Up to 5 TB.

Answer (score 0):

Many online file-sharing services have size limits. For example, [Dropbox limit](https://www.dropbox.com/features/share/send-large-files) is 100 GB, or 250 GB with an [added tool](https://www.dropbox.com/enterprise/creative-tools). [OneDrive also requires additional fees](https://www.popsci.com/share-huge-files-online/) for 250 GB file size limit.

However, it is easy to split and rejoin large files. There are [may Windows tools to do so, such as GSplit](https://whatsoftware.com/how-to-split-and-join-big-files/), and also [numerous alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/gsplit/).

Finally, consider "Sneakernet". A firm at which I worked found it most convenient and economical to send a HDD by mail for weekly file transfers of a huge database. However, now SD and µSD cards are even more practical [if they can withstand mail handling, e.g., X-rays](https://www.thewanderinglensman.com/2014/01/warning-dont-mail-your-memory-cards.html). Check with the carrier's policy for shipping such cards. Considering data transfer rates on some networks, overnight delivery of a data card could be faster, and cheaper than additional data storage fee.